# Reverse geocoding TIGER road data to include US place names

Tags: arcgis-10.2, reverse-geocoding

I downloaded primary, secondary, and local road data in Montana via [USDA](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/); however, place names (city/town etc) are not included in the data sets. I'm just wondering if there is a method to reverse geocode placenames or if there is road data by state that includes placenames? I looked around for place boundary data but was unable to find anything (I'd spatially join the place name to all roads within the place boundary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reverse geocode (that sounds painful).

You should try to download your US datasets from the national map, if at all possible.  This has one of the better interfaces, and the most comprehensive datasets.

Go to
http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/

Then zoom in roughly on Montana.  On the left, you can select Boundaries (this will have town boundaries and names etc.), place names from the GNIS, and Transportation....for starters.  You can download these sets for the state or the selected view area, and it should have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If need be, download your road data, then download boundary data for the towns/cities, and spatially join the name field to the road data.

Edit to add:
Most states have a central GIS service maintain by the state library or a major university.

Montana's appears to be here: http://geoinfo.msl.mt.gov/

I think you might find city data here: http://mslapps.mt.gov/Geographic_Information/Data/DataList/datalist_Details.aspx?did={530355CF-C819-4784-877F-C995C4815D41}

(Found through the link "Data Bundler", under the header "Data Discovery and Access")

Comment: As stated in my question I had looked around for boundary data but couldn't find anything. Do you have any suggestions for a source for this information?

Comment: Ah, I have added info to the answer that may help with boundary data.